# Can External Accessory be run in background for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, external-accessory

Sorry if it is such a dumb question or if I'm not ninja google-ing enough. I just need the answer quick.

I have an external accessory which gets data from ANT+ sensors. My question is, would it be possible that my application using the external accessory continue to run in the background, or at least send push notifications?

Thanks and feel free to downvote because I think it's very lazy of me to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Apple specs your application won't receive events immediately while in the back ground but all events should be hold in a queue and sent when back foreground. Depending on the frequency your device is running and the elapsed time while staying in the background you should be prepared to get a bunch of events.

See [External Accessory Programming Topics: Monitoring Accessory-Related Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Articles/MonitoringEvents.html)

and [Multitasking Support](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1) for more information.